# Dropdown arrow on custom CSS select box not working

Tags: select, drop-down-menu

I am working on the following website and i am having an issue with the dropdown (selectbox) arrow. [url no longer available]

If you click on the second slide of the booking form and then click on the dropdown arrow you will see that it doesn't work. I guess i could start again from scratch if i have to, however, if anyone can think of a quick way to fix this issue i would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: I know this is two years old, but stumbled upon this while browsing for an answer, you can see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811998/customized-select-dropdown-arrow-not-clickable